# Python " is " . a=1 >> a is int >>False .What is going on? is it should not show "True"

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, instanceof

What happened? Why the result is not True?

```
>>>one=1
>>>type(one)
int
>>>one is int
Flase
```

Comment: `is` checks for reference equality.  You need to use `isinstance`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `type` function in order to test the type of an object with the `is` operator:

```
>>> one=1
>>> type(one) is int
True
>>>
```